# How to override standalone component in Angular 16

Tags: angular

I am trying to override a standalone component using `provide` and `useClass`. I created a small example app, that used `<app-card>` in the template. I then use `providers: []` in the app component to replace the `card` component with the `card-override` component. But in stead of showing "card-override works!" I always see "card works!". Why is the component not replaced by the one I list in providers?

#### app.module.ts

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
import { CardOverrideComponent } from './card-override/card-override.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CardComponent, // Import of original component
    CardOverrideComponent, // Import of override component
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
import { CardOverrideComponent } from './card-override/card-override.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ` <app-card></app-card> `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: CardComponent, useClass: CardOverrideComponent }], // Here the original should be replaced by the override
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

#### card.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <p>
      card works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class CardComponent {

}
```

#### card-override.component.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CardComponent } from '../card/card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-override',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <p>
      card-override works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class CardOverrideComponent extends CardComponent {

}
```

Comment: You could use ngComponentOutlet, or the createComponent() method from a ViewContainerRef

Answer (score 0):

Provider cannot be used for components/directives. It is only for classes injected by the DI system.